# Is it acceptable to refer to a grad student as Professor in a paper?

Tags: word-usage

If a grad student is the instructor for a introductory writing course, is it OK for students writing a paper to write ' Professor John Smith' at the top?

Comment: Depends on the institution, but broadly, no. You'd call him a TA or whatever official title the institution has applied to him. For more detailed answers from an academic perspective, you'd probably have better luck asking on our sister site, [Academia.se].

Comment: Would it be acceptable to refer to the person as the Chairman of the Federal Reserve?

Comment: What @deadrat said. Nothing precluded the chairman from also being a grad student - so go for it!

Comment: Define "*OK*" in this context. POB.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really about English language. 'Professor' is a title given to people by academic institutions. If the person has that title, they can be called 'Professor'. If not, then not. It's extremely rare for a grad student to be given the title of 'Professor'.